# Error 999999 calculating Euclidean Distance?

Tags: arcmap, distance, error-999999

I am trying to calculate Euclidean Distance in ArcMap and I keep getting:

> ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
>
> Failed to execute (EucDistance).

I gave a maximum distance of 5000m, output cell size of 10m, set the extent and snap raster env var to my DEM. I tried giving different names to my output distance raster, disabling the background geoprocessing, setting different env var values, but I still getting the same error.

[image: Error]
[image: Settings]

Comment: You should check whether 'Projected Coordinate System' is assigned to your input raster or not. Your input raster must have project coordinate system to take into consideration required distance and output cell size.

Comment: The error occurs quickly, so it has to be fundamental, your output is a geodatabase inside a geodatabase, please check your output path exists, your intended output raster doesn't and you're not editing in that database or have it *schema locked* by ArcCatalog or another ArcMap (close *every other Esri product*), as well as what @Ben said. Error 999999 is a particularly unhelpful error message, it covers a wide range of problems that the original developer didn't foresee and write descriptive error messages for.

Comment: Thank you! The first .gdb in my path (_4ef...gdb) is the windows folder name. The default folder contained a '.gdb' and I did not change it before starting my analysis. The second .gdb "Valmeyer_IL.gdb" is the actual geodatabase. Can I simply remove the ".gdb" from my windows folder name by simple re-naming? Or could that corrupt my project? Thank you!

Comment: Do NOT name any directory with a `.gdb` suffix if you ever want to use it as a plain directory with ArcGIS. This will ***always*** be interpreted as a corrupt path by Esri tools. Anything below the faulty name cannot have been writable, but there's no way to tell what else could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I had a directory named .gdb in the path. Renaming it resolved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Try a different distance method and make sure that your layers have  CS. Another solution to your problem could be to make your polygons into points. Go to ArcToolbox > Spatial Statistic Tools> Measuring Geographic Distributions > Mean Center
and take as input your polygons and output will be the file you want.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. This was actually an invalid path error (.gdb twice), as mentioned in Michael's comment.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, will take the tour that you mentioned. I will try to correct my invalid path. The first .gdb in my path (_4ef...gdb) is the windows folder name. The second .gdb "Valmeyer_IL.gdb" is the actual geodatabase. Can I simply remove the ".gdb" from my windows folder name by simple re-naming? Or could that corrupt my project? Thank you!